# accessing variables in data frame in R

Tags: r, csv

I am try to open all the csv files in my working directory and read all the tables into a large list of data frame. I find a similar solution on stackoverflow and the solution works. The code is:

```
load_data <- function(path) 
{ 
  files <- dir(path, pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)
  tables <- lapply(files, read.csv)
  do.call(rbind, tables)
}
pollutantmean <- load_data("specdata")
```

However, I am confused to some steps. If I delete or omit do.call(rbind,tables), I am not able to access the column variables by calling tables[index]$variable. It returns NULL in the console. Then I try to print an output by calling tables[index] and I do not see any column variables' name appearing the the first row in the table. Can someone explain to me what cause the column variables' name missing and return NULL value?

Comment: Use two brackets `[[` for indexing in that way. The single bracket returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

To see why you are getting `NULL` let's create a reproducible example:

```
df1 <- head(mtcars)
df2 <- head(iris)
my_list <- list(df1, df2)
```

Test the subsetting with one bracket and two:

```
my_list[2]$Species
NULL
my_list[[2]]$Species
[1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Subsetting with two brackets produces the desired output.

**Further Explanation**

Why doesn't one bracket work?

```
> my_list[2]
# [[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

> my_list[[2]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

If someone couldn't tell the difference between the two outputs I wouldn't blame them, they look alike. There's one small important difference between using one bracket and two. The first returns a list, the second returns a data frame. To check, notice the `[[1]]` in the first line of the output of `my_list[2]`. That indicates that the output is a list. As a list we cannot analyze it as we would a data frame. We must use the two brackets to get back a data frame.